# Including C++ Library in Ubuntu/Netbeans

Tags: c++, ubuntu, libraries

I have the SFML library in usr/include/ and if I want to inlcude it, I get the error, that the directory was not found.

I am using Netbeans on Ubuntu and in Tools/Options/C++/ the correct Directory of SFML is included.

Anyone know what the matter could be?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> cd '/home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest' /usr/bin/make -f Makefile
>   CONF=Debug "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
>   SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest' "/usr/bin/make"  -f
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/erstertest make[2]:
>   Entering directory '/home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest' mkdir -p
>   dist/Debug/GNU-Linux g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/erstertest
>   build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o  build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In
>   function `main': /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:5:
>   undefined reference to`sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale
>   const&)' /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:5: undefined
>   reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:5:
>   undefined reference to`sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode,
>   sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:6: undefined reference
>   to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned long)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference
>   to`sf::Color::Green'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference
>   to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:9: undefined reference
>   to`sf::Window::isOpen() const'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:12: undefined
>   reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:15: undefined
>   reference to`sf::Window::close()'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:18: undefined
>   reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned
>   char, unsigned char)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:18: undefined
>   reference to`sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:19: undefined
>   reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:19: undefined
>   reference to`sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&,
>   sf::RenderStates const&)'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:20: undefined
>   reference to `sf::Window::display()'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:5: undefined reference
>   to`sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:24: undefined
>   reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest/main.cpp:5: undefined reference
>   to`sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()' build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o:
>   In function `sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape()':
>   /usr/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to`
>   vtable for sf::CircleShape'
>   /usr/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to
>   `vtable for sf::CircleShape'
>   /usr/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to`
>   sf::Shape::~Shape()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target
>   'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/erstertest' failed make[2]: ***
>   [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/erstertest] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest'
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
>   make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/user/NetBeansProjects/erstertest'
>   nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
>   make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

Comment: How do you include the header files? Where exactly are the main header files? Do you mean `/usr/include` (note the leading slash)? Like in `/usr/include/sfml`? And *what* errors do you get? Please show us the errors, and the code that causes them.

Comment: Be clear about how you are including the files.

Comment: I edited the question, added my code

Comment: Okay, now for the actual error. Please include the (complete, in full and unedited) error message.

Comment: Added it. But I am not sure if I chose the right formating

Comment: Thanks for the the linking. But could you please tell me under which category it falls? I can not see where this is treated.

Comment: So I guess it could be just anything and there is no "easy" way of finding out...